# Removing all directories in a given path with unix

Tags: unix, rm

I have a directory containing lots of files and lots of empty directories. I want to **keep the files** but remove the directories. How can I achieve this using `rm` and other standard unix tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

I believe the `-delete` is a GNUism, in which case you have to do:

```
find . -type d -empty -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

This handles the case of file names with "strange" characters (but it seems `-print0` and `-0` are again GNU extensions).

Comment: if -delete doesn't work, use "find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;" (don't forget the space behind {}, it's important).

Comment: You may need an explicit `-depth` with `find`, depending on the invocation, so that deeper directories are removed first. `-delete` automatically uses `-depth`, the "`find ... -print0 | xargs`" version does not, and would leave file-less directory hierarchies undeleted.